# Run a C# class in command line

Tags: c#, encryption

I have a C# class that Encrypt/Decrypt strings.

Is there any posibilite to run it in the command line?

For example:

> cryptography encrypt "helo world" >> file.txt

I am not very experienced in C# so maybe the solution is quite simple and I do not realize it

Comment: As in a c# console application?

Comment: Compile it to Console Application, pass parameter and then call your class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is basically a "console" application; create a project (or edit your existing project) so that the output type is "Console Application". Then add a `Main` entry-point:

```
public static void Main(string[] args) {
   // TODO: your code here
}
```

The `args` contains the parameters in order; `"encrypt"`, `"hello world"`. Write your output to *stdout* via `Console.Out` typically via `Console.Write` / `Console.WriteLine` - or if you need binary output, `Console.OpenStandardOutput()` - and it will automatically work with pipes such as `>>`. For extra credit, change the return type of `Main` to `int` to return the *errorlevel* of the exe.

Answer (score -1):

create a console application and check the command line arguments

e.g.:

```
static void Main(string[] args){
    if (args.Length == 2)
    {
        if (args[0] == "encrypt")
        {
            Console.WriteLine(encrypt(args[1]));
        } else if(args[0] == "decrypt"){
            Console.WriteLine(decrypt(args[1]));
        }
    }
}
```